# For some reason I'm cant declare a var JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I'm trying to make a consult with an API makes with JS, but at the moment of try through the URL, the variable is not being received, and after I try to put a console.log but it doesn't print on the console, and after that, I've tried to add a var but it doesn't work.

When I try to make a consult, all works in general, but when I add the id on URL, it says to me that doesn't found anything, in this case, I know that an object has the id 14 and I try it `localhost:3000/task/14`.

One document is a *controller.js* another one is a *routes.js*.

```js
const pool = require('./../database/connection')
class TaskController {
    async getTasks (req, res) {
        const result = await pool.query('select * from user');

        res.json({
            code: 200,
            message: "Task retreived successfully",
            data: result
            
        });
    }


    async getTask(req, res) {
        const id = req.params.id;
        let sql = `select * from user where ID_user = ${id}`;
        const task = await pool.query(sql);

        if(task.length == 0) {
            return res.json({
                code: 404,
                message: "Task no found",
                data: [],
            });
        }
        return res.json({
            code:200,
            message: "Task retreived successfully",
            data: [task],
        });
    }

}

const taskController = new TaskController();
module.exports = taskController;
```

It is the route one:

```js
const { Router } = require('express')
const router = Router();
const taskController = require("./../controllers/Task.controller");

router.get("/task", taskController.getTasks)
router.get('/task/:id', taskController.getTask)

module.exports = router;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's ID_user and not the other way around ?

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, SQL doesn't use double equals for comparison

Comment: @BarLevin Yes, is the column ID_user but when I tried to get the id from the URL it doesn't work. I mean with the general consult it gives me all the information correctly but with a specific consult it doesn't  works.

Comment: Off topic, but be **VERY** careful, your code is easily subject to SQL injection, don't use input from the URL directly in a SQL query without sanitizing it first. [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: If type of your `ID_user` is `int` then code seems to be correct. But if it is `string` possibly `varchar` then use `'${id}'` as suggested in asnwer.

Comment: @Karan yes it is an int type, the general consult works but with a specific id it doesn't I think it could be because it is not getting the ":id"

Comment: Everything seems to be legit. If you debug it, is your constant variable id equals 14?

Comment: @seyeredg just write a `console.log(req.params.id)` at the begining of your function to check this.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: @PetrUnzeitig yes it works with an general consul, let me add screenshots

Comment: @Pac0 I'm using mysql

Comment: I'd recommend adding some console.log in `getTask` to check which lines are executed. You should also check your node console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

`select * from user where ID_user = '${id}'`

Comment: What is the difference from what he did ?

Comment: @BarLevin If `ID_user` is `int` then `OP` doesn't need `''` but if it is `string` then `OP` **must** wrap with `''`.

Comment: @piyush that changes nothing :,C

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have type mismatch. Try parsing your ID before putting it to SQL query like this:

```
const id = parseInt(req.params.id);
let sql = `select * from user where ID_user = ${id}`;
```

or if your database column 'ID_user' is defined as text, you should wrap ${id} in quotes:

```
const id = req.params.id;
let sql = `select * from user where ID_user = '${id}'`;
```

Generally make sure you are using the right types in js for types defined in database. You can log the parameter to console and check the type there.